# R-Studio doesn't import files from network drive

Tags: r

I have an issue on my university computer (which university IT can't help me with either).

My files are located on a network drive which gets backuped regularly (hence why I use that one). R and R-Studio are installed on my local drive.

When I want to import files into R-Studio (csv or excel) and those files are located on the network drive, I get the error message "permission denied" in the R cmd window, and R-Studio comes up with "is that a valid excel file? couldn't open file".
However, if I use the cmd and point readcsv() directly to the file, it is working just fine.

So I guess it is an issue with the R-Studio GUI? Anyone an idea on how to fix that?
Both versions of R and R-Studio are the latest.

How I tried to solve the problem:

- Update R and R-Studio
- Use latest portable versions of R and R-Studio
- Run portable versions from the local as well as the network drive

User questions:

- Does R-Studio open the file successfully from the Desktop?
  Not sure if I fully understand the question. If I right click on a CSV file and choose "open with RStudio", the file gets imported correctly.
  When I'm trying to import files (CSV/Excel) that are located on the 'Desktop' using the RStudio GUI ("Import Dataset"), I get the same error message. However, my Desktop is located on a network drive.
  If importing a file via the GUI that's located on the physical hard drive, it works just fine.
- What OS is it running on?
  Windows 7
- are you using a mapped drive or UNC path?
  mapped drives

Comment: It's phrased at the end of the Question like you already solved it.  If not, please Edit the question with these notes : Does R-Studio open the file successfully from the Desktop?  What OS is it running on?  If running Windows, are you using a mapped drive or UNC path?

Comment: Post was edited correspondingly.

Comment: You *could* use VeraCrypt to store files locally, and then use git to push changes to a network drive at the end of the working day.